# Simplify regex code in C#: Add a space between a digit/decimal and unit

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex code written in C# that basically adds a space between a number and a unit with some exceptions:

```
dosage_value = Regex.Replace(dosage_value, @"(\d)\s+", @"$1");
dosage_value = Regex.Replace(dosage_value, @"(\d)%\s+", @"$1%");
dosage_value = Regex.Replace(dosage_value, @"(\d+(\.\d+)?)", @"$1 ");
dosage_value = Regex.Replace(dosage_value, @"(\d)\s+%", @"$1% ");
dosage_value = Regex.Replace(dosage_value, @"(\d)\s+:", @"$1:");
dosage_value = Regex.Replace(dosage_value, @"(\d)\s+e", @"$1e");
dosage_value = Regex.Replace(dosage_value, @"(\d)\s+E", @"$1E");
```

Example:

```
10ANYUNIT
10:something
10 : something
10 %
40 e-5
40 E-05
```

should become

```
10 ANYUNIT
10:something
10: something
10%
40e-5
40E-05
```

Exceptions are: `%, E, e and :`.
I have tried, but since my regex knowledge is not top-notch, would someone be able to help me reduce this code with same expected results?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to provide some sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example data, you might use 2 capture groups where the second group is in an optional part.

In the callback of replace, check if capture group 2 exists. If it does, use is in the replacement, else add a space.

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\s*([%:eE]))?
```

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?:` Non capture group to match a as a whole

  - `\s*([%:eE])` Match optional whitespace chars, and capture 1 of `%` `:` `e` `E` in **group 2**
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b%29%3f%29%28%3f%3a%5cs*%28%5b%25%3aeE%5d%29%29%3f&i=10ANYUNIT%0d%0a10%3asomething%0d%0a10+%3a+something%0d%0a10+%25%0d%0a40+e-5%0d%0a40+E-05)

```
string[] strings = new string[]
{
    "10ANYUNIT",
    "10:something",
    "10 : something",
    "10 %",
    "40 e-5",
    "40 E-05",
};
string pattern = @"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\s*([%:eE]))?";
var result = strings.Select(s => 
    Regex.Replace(
        s, pattern, m => 
        m.Groups[1].Value + (m.Groups[2].Success ? m.Groups[2].Value : " ")
    )
);

Array.ForEach(result.ToArray(), Console.WriteLine);
```

Output

```
10 ANYUNIT
10:something
10: something
10%
40e-5 
40E-05
```

---

As in .NET `\d` can also match digits from other languages, `\s` can also match a newline and the start of the pattern might be a partial match, a bit more precise match can be:

```
\b([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)(?:[\p{Zs}\t]*([%:eE]))?
```

Comment: Nice explanation. I just dont get it how to translate it to the replace part:
Regex.Replace(dosage_value, pattern, @"$1$2 ");
Obviously, @"$1$2 " will not work.

Comment: @user1261558 The array and the Select are only for modifying the array items. If you would write it for a single string, it looks like this `Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("10ANYUNIT", @"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\s*([%:eE]))?", m =>  m.Groups[1].Value + (m.Groups[2].Success ? m.Groups[2].Value : " ")));`

Comment: @user1261558 There are 2 capture groups, the second one is optional. You always use group 1 in the replacement but there has to be something following that according to the examples. Then you check the value of group 2. If there is a group 2, then you also use that value. If there is no group 2, then you append a space (for example in the case of `10 ANYUNIT`) If you use `"$1$2"` then the replacement will be `10ANYUNIT` which does not have a space.

Comment: It seems that if I have "40 mg", it will just add another space and will become "40  mg" (Another extra space)

Comment: So basically, If I already have a "digit AnyUnit", dont add another space.

Comment: @user1261558 Then we can update the logic or the pattern. Do you have a hardcoded list of units? Or do you mean only add a space when there are chars A-Za-z directly following the digits at the start?

Comment: No hardcoded list. Only add a space between any digit and a unit(can be any char). Exceptions: Dont do this when a digit is followed by a :, %, e or E. If a space is already between a digit and unit, dont do anything (except when there is a :, %, e or E. Then concatenate it with the digit like 5e or 5: or 5% e.t.c.)

Comment: @user1261558 Pehaps like this https://regex101.com/r/ZSUQNI/1 See https://ideone.com/AK2Wy0

Comment: More like this: https://regex101.com/r/85fK3Z/1. I want to find all occurrences. Nice website btw, thanks for this!

Comment: @user1261558 Perhaps this would also be a solution https://ideone.com/whf6VI

Comment: Wow, another good site... yes that seems to do what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

`dosage_value = Regex.Replace(dosage_value, @"(\d+(\.\d*)?)\s*((E|e|%|:)+)\s*", @"$1$3 ");`

Group 1 - `(\d+(\.\d*)?)`

Any number like `123` `1241.23`

Group 2 - `((E|e|%|:)+)`

Any of special symbols like E e % :

Group 1 and Group 2 could be separated with any number of whitespaces.

If it's not working as you asking, please provide some samples to test.

Comment: To handle `e-5` you can change pattern to  `@"(\d+(\.\d*)?)\s*((E|e)(-|\+)?\d+|%|:)\s*"` .
Group 3 will be `((E|e)(-|\+)?\d+|%|:)`
it means % or : or e with +|- and couple numbers.

Comment: It does not work as I want. For example, "40mg daily" should be "40 mg daily". Or, "40UNIT" should be "40 UNIT". Exceptions are "E|e|%|:"

Comment: Sorry, forgot about ? on group 3 - @"(\d+(\.\d*)?)\s*((E|e)(-|\+)?\d+|%|:)\s*"

Answer (score 0):

For me it's too complex to be handled just by one regex. I suggest splitting into separate checks. See below code example - I used four different regexes, first is described in detail, the rest can be deduced based on first explanation.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var testStrings = new string[]
{
    "10mg",
    "10:something",
    "10  :   something",
    "10 %",
    "40 e-5",
    "40 E-05",
};

foreach (var testString in testStrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Input: '{testString}', parsed: '{RegexReplace(testString)}'");
}


string RegexReplace(string input)
{
    // First look for exponential notation.
    // Pattern is: match zero or more whitespaces \s*
    // Then match one or more digits and store it in first capturing group (\d+)
    // Then match one ore more whitespaces again.
    // Then match part with exponent ([eE][-+]?\d+) and store it in second capturing group.
    // It will match lower or uppercase 'e' with optional (due to ? operator) dash/plus sign and one ore more digits.
    // Then match zero or more white spaces.
    var expForMatch = Regex.Match(input, @"\s*(\d+)\s+([eE][-+]?\d+)\s*");
    if(expForMatch.Success)
    {
        return $"{expForMatch.Groups[1].Value}{expForMatch.Groups[2].Value}";
    }

    var matchWithColon = Regex.Match(input, @"\s*(\d+)\s*:\s*(\w+)");
    if (matchWithColon.Success)
    {
        return $"{matchWithColon.Groups[1].Value}:{matchWithColon.Groups[2].Value}";
    }

    var matchWithPercent = Regex.Match(input, @"\s*(\d+)\s*%");
    if (matchWithPercent.Success)
    {
        return $"{matchWithPercent.Groups[1].Value}%";
    }

    var matchWithUnit = Regex.Match(input, @"\s*(\d+)\s*(\w+)");
    if (matchWithUnit.Success)
    {
        return $"{matchWithUnit.Groups[1].Value} {matchWithUnit.Groups[2].Value}";
    }

    return input;
}
```

Output is:

```
Input: '10mg', parsed: '10 mg'
Input: '10:something', parsed: '10:something'
Input: '10  :   something', parsed: '10:something'
Input: '10 %', parsed: '10%'
Input: '40 e-5', parsed: '40e-5'
Input: '40 E-05', parsed: '40E-05'
```

Comment: E-notation numbers could be written as `e+5` `e5` `e-5`